# copy list initialization vs direct list initialization of temporary

Tags: c++11, move, temporary-objects, list-initialization

Given the following struct:

```
struct ABC
{
    ABC(){cout << "ABC" << endl;}
    ~ABC() noexcept {cout << "~ABC" << endl;}
    ABC(ABC const&) {cout << "copy" << endl;}
    ABC(ABC&&) noexcept {cout << "move" << endl;}
    ABC& operator=(ABC const&){cout << "copy=" << endl;}
    ABC& operator=(ABC&&) noexcept {cout << "move=" << endl;}
};
```

The output of:

```
std::pair<std::string, ABC> myPair{{}, {}};
```

is:

```
ABC
copy
~ABC
~ABC
```

While the output of:

```
std::pair<std::string, ABC> myPair{{}, ABC{}};
```

is:

```
ABC
move
~ABC
~ABC
```

In attempting to understand the difference between the two I think I have identified that the first case is using copy-list-initialization, while the second one uses direct-list-initialization of an unnamed temporary (numbers 7 and 2, respectively, in here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Searching for similar questions I've found this: [Why does the standard differentiate between direct-list-initialization and copy-list-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461027/why-does-the-standard-differentiate-between-direct-list-initialization-and-copy) and this: [Does copy list initialization invoke copy ctor conceptually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964221/does-copy-list-initialization-invoke-copy-ctor-conceptually).

The answers in those questions discuss the fact that for copy-list-initialization, the use of an explicit constructor would render the code ill-formed. In fact, if I make ABC's default constructor explicit, my first example won't compile but that is (perhaps) a different matter.

So, the question is: Why is the temporary copied in the first case but moved in the second? What prevents it from being moved in the case of copy-list-initialization?

As a note, the following code:

```
std::pair<std::string, ABC> myPair = std::make_pair<string, ABC>({}, {});
```

Also results in a call to ABC's move constructor (and no copy constructor call), but different mechanisms may be involved.

You can try the code out (using gcc-4.9.2 in C++14 mode) at: https://ideone.com/Kc8xIn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, *braced-init-lists* like `{}` are not expressions and do not have a type. If you have a function template

```
template<typename T> void f(T);
```

and call `f( {} )`, no type will be deduced for `T`, and type deduction will fail.

On the other hand, `ABC{}` is a prvalue expression of type `ABC` (an "explicit type conversion in functional notation"). For a call like `f( ABC{} )`, the function template can deduce the type `ABC` from this expression.

---

In C++14, as well as in C++11, `std::pair` has the following constructors [pairs.pair]; `T1` and `T2` are the names of the template parameter of the `std::pair` class template:

> ```
> pair(const pair&) = default;
> pair(pair&&) = default;
> constexpr pair();
> constexpr pair(const T1& x, const T2& y);
> template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(U&& x, V&& y);
> template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(const pair<U, V>& p);
> template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(pair<U, V>&& p);
> template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
> pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<Args1...>, tuple<Args2...>);
> ```

Note that there is a constructor

> ```
> constexpr pair(const T1& x, const T2& y); // (C)
> ```

But no

> ```
> constexpr pair(T1&& x, T2&& y);
> ```

instead, there is a perfectly forwarding

> ```
> template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(U&& x, V&& y); // (P)
> ```

If you try to initialize a `std::pair` with two initializers where at least one of them is a *braced-init-list*, the constructor (P) is not viable since it cannot deduce its template arguments.

(C) is not a constructor template. Its parameter types `T1 const&` and `T2 const&` are fixed by the class template parameters. A reference to a constant type can be initialized from an empty *braced-init-list*. This creates a temporary object that is bound to the reference. As the type referred to is const, the (C) constructor will copy its arguments into the class' data members.

---

When you initialize a pair via `std::pair<T,U>{ T{}, U{} }`, the `T{}` and `U{}` are prvalue-expressions. The constructor template (P) can deduce their types and is viable. The instantiation produced after type deduction is a better match than the (C) constructor, because (P) will produce rvalue-reference parameters and bind the prvalue arguments to them. (C) on the other hand binds the prvalue arguments to lvalue-references.

---

Why then does the live example move the second argument when called via `std::pair<T,U>{ {}, U{} }`?

libstdc++ defines additional constructors. Below is an extract of its `std::pair` implementation from 78536ab78e, omitting function definitions, some comments, and SFINAE. `_T1` and `_T2` are the names of the template parameters of the `std::pair` class template.

```
  _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR pair();

  _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR pair(const _T1& __a, const _T2& __b); // (C)

  template<class _U1, class _U2>
constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p);

  constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
  constexpr pair(pair&&) = default;

  // DR 811.
  template<class _U1>
constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y); // (X)

  template<class _U2>
constexpr pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y); // (E) <=====================

  template<class _U1, class _U2>
constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y);      // (P)

  template<class _U1, class _U2>
constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p);

  template<typename... _Args1, typename... _Args2>
    pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args1...>, tuple<_Args2...>);
```

Note the (E) constructor template: It will copy the first argument and perfectly forward the second. For an initialization like `std::pair<T,U>{ {}, U{} }`, it is viable because it only needs to deduce a type from the second argument. It is also a better match than (C) for the second argument, and hence a better match overall.

The "DR 811" comment is in the libstdc++ sources. It refers to [LWG DR 811](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#811) which adds some SFINAE, but no new constructors.

The constructors (E) and (X) are a libstdc++ extension. I'm not sure if it's compliant, though.

libc++ on the other hand does not have this additional constructors. For the example `std::pair<T,U>{ {}, U{} }`, it will [copy the second argument](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6f0777bf7cc2f36).

[Live demo with both library implementations](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d4a6a920bbf1845)

Comment: how can perfectly-forwarding constructor be selected for `myPair{{}, ABC{}};` call, if it can't deduce `std::string` from `{}`?

Comment: @MarcAndreson Oops, my bad. I misread this. If you're using libstdc++, this might be an extension. Let me try to look it up.

Comment: The reason for those overloads is mostly to support stuff like `std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int>, int *> p(std::unique_ptr<int>(), 0);`. See [PR 40925](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40925#c8),

Comment: @T.C. PR 40925 seems to contain an example similar to LWG 811, but there's a comma at the end of your comment. Is there anything missing?

Comment: @dyp I was linking to comment 8, which is the commit adding those overloads with the comment *Add, to deal correctly with move-only types in the presence of "null pointers"*.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, thanks. It did not occur to me to look into the commit/change message of that comment. I've added it and the example to my email to std-discussion.