# List-initialization of an array without temporaries - not working in GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer

Consider the following contrived example

```
struct A {
    A(int) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    ~A() {}
};

struct B {
    A a[2] = {{1}, {2}};
};

int main() {
    B b;
}
```

It compiles fine in **clang** (any version) but not in **GCC** (any version, any standard >= C++11)

```
<source>: In constructor 'constexpr B::B()':
<source>:7:8: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'
 struct B {
        ^
<source>:3:5: note: declared here
     A(const A&) = delete;
     ^
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:12:7: note: synthesized method 'constexpr B::B()' first required here
     B b;
       ^
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/DneRbb)

When A's destructor is commented out, it compiles fine also in GCC.

**Question is** - who is right, clang or GCC, and why?

Initially I thought GCC is wrong, but then I saw [[dcl.init.list]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.list#5) which states that temporaries are created. Though I'm not sure if that applies here or if there's another rule that overrides this.

Comment: `[dcl.init.list]/5` does not apply because you are doing aggregate initialization of `a`.

Comment: Even if a copy can be elided, the copy-constructor needs to exist.

Comment: @NathanOliver - A is not an aggregate, as it has a constructor.

Comment: But `A[2]` *is* an aggregate

Comment: @rustyx `a`, not `A`.  All arrays are aggregates even if they are made of non aggregates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does copy list initialization invoke copy ctor conceptually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964221/does-copy-list-initialization-invoke-copy-ctor-conceptually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [an array is an aggregate](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.aggr#def:aggregate) and [aggregate initialization comes down to copy-initialization of aggregate members from the corresponding initializer-clauses](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.aggr#2), the question basically is: does copy-list-initialization (of array elements `a[0]` and `a[1]` from `{1}` and `{2}`, respectively) require copy constructor, but [such question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26964221/9585016) has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26964314/9585016) — it does not.

BTW, GCC accepts `A a = {1};`, i.e. it has no problem with "direct" copy-list-initialization, but does not treat it correctly when members of aggregates are initialized.