# Why does copy initialisation with braces elide copy/move construction?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, language-lawyer, copy-elision

Here is a C++ 14 program for comparing [*direct initialisation*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) (no `=`) with [*copy initialisation*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (`=`):*

```cpp
#include <iostream>


struct A {
    A(int) { std::cout << "A(int)" << std::endl; }
    A(A&) { std::cout << "A(A&)" << std::endl; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout << "A(A&&)" << std::endl; }
};


int main() {
    A a(1);     // direct initialisation
    A b{1};     // direct initialisation
    A c = 1;    // copy initialisation
    A d = (1);  // copy initialisation
    A e = {1};  // copy initialisation
}
```

Compiling the program *with [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) disabled* and running it:

```sh
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -fno-elide-constructors main.cpp && ./a.out
```

produces the following output:

```cpp
A(int)
A(int)
A(int)
A(A&&)
A(int)
A(A&&)
A(int)
```

**Why does copy initialisation with braces (`A e = {1};`) elide copy/move construction (even with copy elision disabled)?**

---

<sup>* The motivation behind this comparison was to understand how a function return statement (`return expression`) works since C++ 11. When returning by value, one can use direct initialisation or copy initialisation of the function return value. The latter is more complex than copy initialisation of a variable like here, because initialising the function return value from the object denoted by `expression` involves [trying to call the move constructor of the function return type first](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) (even if `expression` is an lvalue) before falling back on its copy constructor. And since C++ 17, that copy/move construction *is guaranteed* to be elided if `expression` is a prvalue (mandatory [*return value optimisation*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)), while it *might* be elided if `expression` is a glvalue (optional [*named return value optimisation*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)).</sup>

Comment: Cases c and e never involve the copy constructor in the first place.

Comment: @jamesdlin: `c` does in C++14, though it is almost certainly always to be elided. Copy-initialization of a `T` from an object that isn't a `T` requires the creation of a temporary of type `T` via conversion, then using that temporary to initialize `c`. C++17's guaranteed elision rules make the "temporary" into a prvalue of type `T` and thus skip any copy/move from the prvalue created to the object being initialized.

Comment: I think it is correct to say that `T x = {y};` is identical to `T x{y};` other than checking for  explicit constructors?

Comment: @NicolBolas "Copy-initialization of a `T` from an object that isn't a `T` requires the creation of a temporary of type `T` via conversion, then using that temporary to initialize `c`" I guess you meant via *implicit* conversion, and that `A a = A(1);` would be the creation of a temporary object via *explicit* conversion?

Comment: Dup of [Does copy list initialization invoke copy ctor conceptually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964221/does-copy-list-initialization-invoke-copy-ctor-conceptually)

Comment: @M.M Yes, cf. the link provided by LanguageLawyer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> copy initialisation with braces

There is no such thing. If you use a braced-init-list to initialize an object, you are performing some form of *list initialization*. There are two forms of this: copy-list-initialization, and direct-list-initialization. In C++14, these have no relation to copy-initialization and direct-initialization (technically, direct-list-initialization is a [grammatical form of direct-initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init#16), but since [list-initialization bypasses everything that direct-initialization would have done](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init#17.1), it's easier to say that direct-list-initialization is its own beast).

List initialization as a concept initializes an object. Using `Typename t{}` is direct-list-initialization, while `Typename t = {}` is copy-list-initialization. But regardless of which form is involved, *no temporary is created*; list initialization initializes the object in question. The only object in your example is `e`, so that is the object which gets initialized.

In accord with the [C++14 rules for list-initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.list#3), `e` gets initialized by [calling a constructor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.list#3.4), passing it a value of `1`, which is the only value in the braced-init-list.

Comment: Is the fact that both direct-list-initialisation and copy-list-initialisation do not create temporary objects the reason why braces are called the [uniform initialisation syntax](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/133688/184279)?

Comment: @Maggyero: No; it was deemed "uniform initialization" because the idea was that the initialization rules would be the same in all places, that regardless of how you used the `{}`, for any given `T` being initialized and for any given set of parameters, the same rules for initialization would apply. Obviously, the whole copy/direct-list-initialization distinction made that non-functional..